# synchronize E mail automatically with database

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I wanted to know from you whether it is possible to check an email entry, if it exists already in the database and to display a message .
This validation should work dynamically without a button.

I work with jsf 2.1 and prime faces 3.5
I hope you understand what I mean and thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you know how to implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement a custom validator. Full explanation in [this guide](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/custom-validator-in-jsf-2-0/)

Snippet code:

```
<h:inputText id="email" value="#{bean.email}">
    <f:validator validatorId="myEmailValidator" />
    <f:ajax event="keyup" render="emailError" />
</h:inputText>
<h:message id="emailError" for="email" />
```

Comment: thanks I will try to implement it and if it works I will post it